# git pull on running code causes corruption

Tags: python, git, flask

We are developing a product running on a `RPI CM3+ module` (Buster OS). It is WiFi connected and runs a python flask server.

The code (server.py) is run from a locally cloned `git` repository. We have a page on the server where the idea is that the user can check if there are any remote updates by clicking a button on the flask UI.

The issue seems to be that when we do a `git pull`. The `server.py` file size becomes 0kB and when we subsequently try and interact with the `git` we get:

`error: object file .git/objects/3b/1f1939a417f8bbb15e759c899911cc664b5488 is empty`

`fatal: loose object 3b1f1939a417f8bbb15e759c899911cc664b5488 (stored in .git/objects/3b/1f1939a417f8bbb15e759c899911cc664b5488) is corrupt`

We have to remove and re-clone the repository.

Is this expected behaviour for performing a `git pull` on running code? What procedure should we be following to achieve a method of remote code update for our product?

Comment: *Is this expected behaviour for performing a git pull on running code?* No, but I'd suggest not using Git at all for deployment (use a real deployment tool if possible) or at least, not using `git pull`: it's meant to be used by a human, not a computer program. To (ab?)use Git as a deployment tool, use `git fetch` and then some other more-script-able Git command. That probably won't fix *this* though: this error makes no sense, as object files should never be *empty*.

Comment: @torek what "real deployment tool" do you recommend? You recommend not using git, but then recommend using `git fetch`? 'fetch` as far as I understand it is only, downloads but does not integrate the new data into the files.

Comment: I don't have any recommendations for deployment tools, unfortunately. I just know that when I've abused Git as one in the past, it's never really worked as well as I wanted. :-) As for fetch vs pull: `pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. The choice of second command is up to the user, but it defaults to `git merge`. This is rarely the right thing to do: usually you want instead to check out some specific commit. Merge will do that in some cases, but will perform a merge, or—worse—stop with a merge conflict in others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a custom workflow. I took the advice of @torek and moved away from using `git` as this was corrupting itself and my code.

The approach I took was a 3 step approach

**Step 1.** I created an `API` which allowed the application to check if a new version existed. For this I used `AWS lambda` and `AWS API Gateway`. I hosted my new code in a `.zip` file in an `AWS S3 bucket`.

**Step 2.** Since my application is in `python` then if the `API` returned a `true` stating that a version existed then I would use:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('bucket', '<code_folder_in_bucket>', '<download_dir_on_devivce')
```

**Step 3.** I created a bash service that runs on start-up (systemd) that checks if a `.zip` folder exists in a specific directory. If it does then it performs an `unzip`and overwrites the application folder with the new code. Deleting the `.zip` folder afterwards for a clean start next time. The service after this service is the service to launch my application code.

This works very reliably.